# How to find the 10 biggest directories modified in the last 10 days and sort them using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find the 10 biggest directories that were modified in the last 10 days and sort them by size using bash.

I'd need to get the size in a human readable format.

It would be easy to get the directory size in a nice format using du:

```
sudo du -h /mypath/ --max-depth=1
```

But du has no option to add the modified in the last 10 days bit

That is why I've been also trying to use find:

```
sudo find /mypath/e -xdev -depth -type d -ls -mtime 10
```

But in this case I cannot get sizes.

I've been trying to mix and match several other questions here in StackOverflow and I've found that I could use xargs but still the output doesn't look right:

```
sudo find /mypath/ -mtime -10 -type d  | xargs ls -la
```

I am still trying many options but I cannot find the good, reliable and elegant solution for this.

Can you please help?

Comment: "Modified" and "big": (1) a directory could be modified by having a single small file in it added then removed, leaving nothing but old (but perhaps very large) files behind. Do you wish this directory counted as "modified"? (2) how do you measure the size of directories? all files in all subdirectories? just the files in the top level of a given directory? just the files 10 days old or less? (I guess I'm wondering if there's some structure under /mypath that makes the task easier.)

Comment: Thanks for your input! 1 is yes, counts as modified and 2 output should just name the directory and its size (it is OK if I also get permissions or other stuff, that can be filtered). I need no files, just directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No elegant, but one way of separating recently-modified directories, computing their storage, sorting the results, and displaying the summary. Handles file names with spaces in their names ok, but not tabs or newlines. (Exercise for the reader.)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) <directory>" >&2
  exit 1
fi

find "$1" -mindepth 1 -xdev \
    -type d -mtime -10 |         # subdirs of $1 modified in last 10 days
  xargs -r -n 1 -d $'\n' du -s | # total storage in each such subdir
  sort -t $'\t' -k 1nr,1 |       # sorted in descending order
  head -10 |                     # first 10 are "top 10"
  awk -F $'\t' '{print $2}' |    # emit just the subdirs
  xargs -r -n 1 -d $'\n' du -sh  # total, human-readable, for those 10
```

Comment: It is perfectly matching my request!
Really thanks for your help and going the extra mile in detailing comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sudo find /mypath/ -mtime -10 -type d  | xargs ls -ldrt
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It seems to work fine but I do not get human readable sizes...

Comment: You can use `bc` or `$(())` to divide the sizes by appropriate factors

Comment: Can you please share an example?